# Access mounted directory in Linux

Tags: linux, mount, aws, amazon-ec2

I have mounted 2 directories in my Linux system.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           7.7G  1.2M  7.7G   1% /run
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1   20G   16G  4.9G  76% /
/dev/nvme1n1    100G   47G   54G  47% /data
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

One of the mounted directories is 76 percent full now. 
And I need to access that directory to remove unnecessary files. 
However, I am not able to access that directory by any means. 
If I do `cd /`, it does not look like the mounted directory.

How can I resolve this situation?

Comment: Welcome on U&L! What makes you believe that `cd /` is not bringing you to the root directory of the file system on the `/dev/nvme0n1p1` device?

Comment: (1) Illustrations are supposed to ***illustrate*** the post.  While raw data can be useful, I don’t see anything in your `df -h` listing that tells me anything useful about your situation.  Where are your two “mounted directories”?  (2) Strictly speaking, it’s impossible for a directory to be *nn* % full.  *Filesystems* can be *nn* % full.  If you don’t know the difference between a directory and a filesystem, please look it up.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) According to the `df -h` listing, the only filesystem that’s 76% full is the root filesystem (`/`).  It’s impossible for the root filesystem to be one of your two “mounted directories”, so what are you talking about? (4) Repeating fra-san’s question: what do you see when you `cd /`, what do you expect to see, and how are they different? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.